# How to enable ForceType in Apache with mod_fcgid

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have `mod_spdy`, so I had to enable `mod_fcgid` for PHP [per instructions from Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php). The config looks like this:

```
<Location />
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
Options +ExecCGI
FcgidWrapper /usr/bin/php-cgi .php
</Location>
```

However, now `ForceType application/x-httpd-php` isn't working.

This was what I had before:

```
<FilesMatch (index.html|foo|bar)>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

But it's now being ignored -- i.e. the PHP is being rendered instead of preprocessed. Here's what happens:

```
$ curl -i http://blahblah.ca/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Dec 2012 15:19:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Apr 2010 20:49:57 GMT
ETag: "494bb1-676-483abb4742740"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1654
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
```

How can I have ForceType work with mod_fcgid?

Comment: Try [`SetHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#sethandler) instead of `ForceType`?

Comment: `SetHandler  application/x-httpd-php`? No luck.

Comment: Na, `SetHandler fcgid-script`, it might just work.

Comment: I end up with two errors: `(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://blah/` and `Premature end of script headers: about, referer: http://blah/`

Comment: Well, at least that's an improvement.  Unfortunately we've now exhausted my FastCGI experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<FilesMatch (index.html|foo|bar)>
  SetHandler fcgid-script
  FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```